# Finding common strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to find common strings in given two strings.

Example:

```
string1 = "mega,cloud,two,website,final"
string2 = "window,penguin,literature,network,fun,cloud,final,sausage"
answer = "cloud,final,two"
```

So far this is what i got:

```
function commonWords(first, second) {
    var words = first.match(/\w+/g);
    var result = "";
    words.sort();
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        if(second.includes(words[i])){
            result = result.concat(words[i]);
            result += ",";
        }
    }
    result = result.substr(0, result.length -1);
    return result;

}
```

But the result that i got is :

```
answer = cloud,final
```

Can you help me out please? First time asking question on StackOverFlow, so sorry for the typing.

Comment: Why `two` when there is no `two` string in second string

Comment: Where is two coming from? Did you forget to add it in the second string in the example?

Comment: If you want to find the two string from network then you can't use the w+ which define word boundaries !

Comment: Okey i believe two comes from "network", which it shouldn't. I should use something different than 'includes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is first [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the two strings, then do a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and check if the other string includes the current string. If so add them to a new array.

```js
const string1 = "mega,cloud,two,website,final"
const string2 = "window,penguin,literature,network,fun,cloud,final,sausage"

const array1 = string1.split(',')
const array2 = string2.split(',')

const result = array1.reduce((arr, val) => array2.includes(val) ? arr.concat(val) : arr, [])

console.log(result)
// Convert it to a string if desired
console.log(result.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert each string to an array of words with [`.split(',')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Then filter the first array with [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) by checking if each item of the array is in the other one:

```js
string1 = "mega,Cloud,two,website,final"
string2 = "window,penguin,literature,network,fun,cloud,final,sausage"

array1 = string1.toLowerCase().split(',')
array2 = string2.toLowerCase().split(',')
var a = array1.filter(word => -1 !== array2.indexOf(word));

console.log(a)
```

Before converting the string to an array I have applied `.toLowerCase()` so that the script can return `cloud` in the result if it appears in the first one as "**C**loud" and in the second as "**c**loud"

Comment: might want to do some trimming since you introduced extra spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
string1 = "mega,cloud,two,website,final"
string2 = "window,penguin,literature,network,fun,cloud,final,sausage";
var arr1= string1.split(",");
var arr2 = string2.split(",");

var result = [];
arr1.forEach(function(str){
 arr2.forEach(function(str2){
    if(str2.indexOf(str) != -1)
      result.push(str);
 });
});
var answer = result.join(",");
console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your function is you also converting the string to into second as an array.

```
function commonWords(first, second) {
    var words = first.match(/\w+/g); // word is a array type
    var result = ""; 
    words.sort();
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        if(second.includes(words[i])){ //second should be string type
            result = result.concat(words[i]);
            result += ",";
        }
    }
    result = result.substr(0, result.length -1);
    return result;

}
```

Or you can try this

```
    first = "mega,cloud,two,website,final"
second = "window,penguin,literature,network,fun,cloud,final,sausage"

function commonWords(first, second) {
    var words = first.match(/\w+/g);
    var result = "";
    words.sort();
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        if(second.includes(words[i])){
            result = result.concat(words[i]);
            result += ",";
        }
    }
    result = result.substr(0, result.length -1);
    return result;

}

console.log(commonWords(first, second));
```